# how to bind object coming from jsp in spring controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

```
<c:forEach items="${assetList}" var="ast">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="assets-vehicle-profile/${ast}">${ast.id}</a></td>
    <td>${ast.make}</td>
    <td>${ast.model}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

controller logic:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/assets-details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String assetsDisplay(ModelMap map) {
    return new ModelAndView("assets- details","assetsList",assetManager.getAllAssets())
}
```

For above request (assets-details) it works fine, it displays all records in assets table

```
@RequestMapping("/assets-vehicle-profile/{ast}")
public ModelAndView deleteIssue(@PathVariable("ast") AssetEntity asset ) {

    return new ModelAndView("assets-vehicle-profile","model",asset);
}
```

My requirement is when user click on (assets-vehicle-profile) asset-id i want to send object belongs to that asset id to the controller to display some more fieds in other (asset-vehicle-profile) jsp

Request:

```
http://localhost:8080/infra/assets-vehicle-profile/com.leadwinner.infra.entity.AssetEntity@1e5addc
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.leadwinner.infra.entity.AssetEntity]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so your method

```
public ModelAndView deleteIssue(@PathVariable("ast") AssetEntity asset ) {
```

is expecting an `AssetEntity` but of course the JSP is only sending a String, so change it to

```
public ModelAndView deleteIssue(@PathVariable("ast") String assetId ) {

     // look up asset from DB ?

}
```

Comment: to minimize the db hitting. I want to use same object to display full information about that asset @Scary Wombat

Comment: tell me how to catch that object or like string again how to convert that string to my class  @Scary Wombat

Comment: You could cache the object yourself in some type of List, but I would rather go for some standard DB caching (maybe Ehcache)

Comment: what do you mean by `tell me how to catch that object or like string again how to convert that string to my class `

Comment: i want to use same object to display full profile in another jsp (without hitting DB again) -@Scary Wombat

Comment: If you use a DB cache as I suggested, then it is very very likely that you will not need to `hit` the DB again (that is the meaning of a cache).  if you choose not to use a DB cache then you will need to cache all of the results of `assetManager.getAllAssets()` yourself, and consider what will happen if another user adds, deletes or changes an Asset.  A DB cache is the industry standard way of doing this type of coding